# Converting legacy GRUB menu entries to GRUB 2

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, grub2

I would like to change an entry for a solution to boot from CD from legacy grub (looks like `title bla bla bla`) to an entry to a format compatible to grub 2 (the one that looks like `menuentry "bla bla bla" {`.

The original legacy GRUB entry is as follows:

```
title Boot From CD/DVD Drive
    kernel /boot/grub/memdisk.din
    initrd /boot/grub/sbootmgr.dsk
```

Is there any sort of conversion rule to change this to something like the example I've put here on the next line? (This is from my precise's grub.cfg.)

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-25-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos8)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root efc87ac0-daac-4a32-9a85-ea57beff0e28
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-25-generic root=UUID=efc87ac0-daac-4a32-9a85-ea57beff0e28 ro   quiet splash acpi_osi= $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-25-generic
}
```

Comment: And yeah, I know I already asked on Ask Ubuntu.  My last question I did the same, though - and you guys answered it in 40mins!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you bend grub-mkconfig to do what you want?

http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Simple-configuration

Comment: I think so, so I think I'll give you the answer even though I don't right now have quite the inclination (I've given up on this particular troubleshooting thing).